# Send data from routeHandler to a partial in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, routes, handlebars.js, partial

I have a variable which contains some data. This variable is in a routeHandler file called content.js. Now i have to pass this variable to a partial called nav.hbs that uses it for some calculation. Can anyone help me out with this? Very new to NodeJS.

PS:- I am using handlebars to design the partial.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or maybe just look here https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/ it's all there

Comment: @Molda I tried doing res.render('nav', {'Index': data}) , it renders the leftnav which i don't want because i have to do operations on the index first. And moreover nav is a partial. Don't know if i can render.

Comment: To render index you call `res.render('index',{ data: data });` the data variable can have data for partials that you include using {{> partial-name }} in index.html

Comment: @Molda No. Index will be the {{ }} which will have the info from data. I can't render index. i just want to send the data from content.js to the partial nav.hbs. Don't know which command i should use now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to render the nav that you include in some other page before send to client? That's what you would normally do. Why you can't render index?

Comment: @Molda The nav.hbs is a partial. It builds a dynamic list. Now the data for that list is in the file content.js in the variable data. This nav.hbs is a part of a view called content.hbs. So before rendering the view content.hbs, i have to populate that dynamic list with data and then render the content.hbs which will in turn load that list.

Comment: That's what I thought so you call `res.render('content',{ data: data  });` in content.hbs you should include your nav using {{> nav}} , the data is available in both the content.hbs and the nav.hbs so in your route handler get all data needed for nav and content and pass them to res.render done.

Comment: @MoldaThat gave me some good start. Thanks a ton for the patience :)